# How to copy file from one use to another?

Tags: permissions, sudo, users, file-copy

I have a web server and it using by few developers.
Web-site is under `website` user. Other users are like `user1`, `user2` etc.
I have given sudo access to `user1`, `user2`.. to access `website`.

The issue I'm having now is users fails to copy scripts from `website` because some scripts not allows to read directly by the `users`. And even if I try to cp using sudo it fails because `website` don't have write permission to `users` directories.

I do not want to change the file permission due to some security seasons.
i saw somewhere that I can do this using tar, but couldn't figure out.

Can someone help...

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have root access?

Comment: When you do `sudo cp`, you are not running as `website` but `root`, so, permissions shouldn't be an issue. Are they all on the same filesystem? Is the website and the user's ssh sessions running on different containers? Can you post a terminal transcript showing how it fails?

Comment: Hydranix Yes I'm root. rbanffy All this system is on debian server. We actually allow users to do sudo -u website cp. So they never run command as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do (as `user1`) something like

```
sudo -u website cat ~website/somefile > ~user1/somefile
```

Note that `~user1/somefile` will be firstly created by user running the shell (`user1`), and the `cat` will be executed as `website`

You can use tar(1) with same trick, for multiple files:

```
sudo -u website tar cf - ~website/foo ~website/bar | tar xf -
```

Run as `user1` in his directory, that will "create" tar archive on stdout as `website`, and the another tar (without sudo, so running as same user as the one running the shell, that is `user1`) would unpack that virtual tar file to current directory (to which `user1`  can write).

**UPDATE** Note that tar will create subdirectories leading to a file, you can reduce that behaviour by specifying `-C` so tar will entet specified directory before starting:

```
sudo -u website tar -C ~website -cf - foo bar | tar xf -
```

This way,  `foo` and `bar` will be created in current directory without leading subdirectories (but if you added `blah/baz`, it would create `blah` as subdir in which `baz` resides)

Comment: Thanks a lot Matija. You save my day. cat command solution is good to cp single file. I think tar is good for multiple files. However I tried your tar command for a particular file like below, it result was copied entire /home dir set. Command : sudo -u website tar cf - /home/website/DB.php | tar xf -

Comment: @YasiruG no, I do not think it did copy whole `/home`. But it did create all the leading subdirectories for `DB.php`. See update to the answer for how to avoid that.

Comment: yup, you are correct. Thanks for that. I think you need to do small correction. command should be sudo -u website tar cf -C ~website foo bar | tar xf -